# Customize the postamble of html publishing in org-mode

Tags: html, publish, org-mode

SO is full with methods how to customize the postamble of HTML exporting. However, I failed to find how to define a customized postamble per project when using `org-publish`. I found a way to remove the postamble; add the following option to the project's definition in `org-publish-project-alist`:

```
:html-postamble nil
```

But I didn't find a way to define a customized postamble for a specific project.

Ideas?

### Edit:

So I added

```
:html-postamble "<hr><p class=\"date\">Last edit: %d</p>"
```

but the date doesn't render. So I [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17685469/671013):

```
:html-postamble "en" "<hr><p class=\"date\">Last edit: %d</p>"
```

but for vain...

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
(setq org-export-html-postamble-format
  '(("en" "<p class=\"creator\">%c</p>
           <p class=\"time\">%T</p>               
           <p class=\"xhtml-validation\">%v</p>"));
) ;; End bracket
```

Look at [How do I format the postamble in HTML-export with Org-mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742836/how-do-i-format-the-postamble-in-html-export-with-org-mode)